# How to Solve an error that happens due to memory exhaustion?

Tags: r, error-handling, out-of-memory

I am trying to run the following code in a code chunk in Rmarkdown:

```
stations2 <- all_year %>%
  mutate(start_station_name = na_if(start_station_name, "")) %>%
  unique() %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  group_by(member_casual, start_station_name) %>%
  summarise(trip_number = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = member_casual,
              values_from = trip_number,
              values_fill = 0)
```

And I got the following error once:
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `start_station_name`.
i `start_station_name = na_if(start_station_name, "")`.
x cannot allocate vector of size 32.6 Mb

And then, I got another error when I run again the chunk:
Error: memory exhausted (limit reached?)

The all_year dataset contains over 4 million rows.

Is there a way to run that chunk of code, even at a slower pace?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You may benefit from shifting to a `data.table` paradigm, where the referential semantics (in-place operations) are more memory efficient (and often faster). It has a steep learning curve, but (imo) very much worth it when working with large-ish data. For example, *that* NA-replacing code might be `all_year[start_station_name == "", start_station_name := NA_character_]`.

Comment: (BTW: many, most, perhaps all (untested) of `dplyr` verbs will work on `data.table`, though most of them will return a `tibble` which will defeat the in-place operations you need. You might do most of your processing in `dplyr` still, then to this op and any other that are grossly expensive, and then switch back to `dplyr`-mode. It may be what is necessary to get you past this memory-exhaustion. There is also [`dtplyr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dtplyr/index.html), which may be more friendly to you, though I have not used/tested it.)